# How to write a confusion matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I wrote a confusion matrix calculation code in Python:

```
def conf_mat(prob_arr, input_arr):
    # confusion matrix
    conf_arr = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]

    for i in range(len(prob_arr)):
        if int(input_arr[i]) == 1:
            if float(prob_arr[i]) < 0.5:
                conf_arr[0][1] = conf_arr[0][1] + 1
            else:
                conf_arr[0][0] = conf_arr[0][0] + 1
        elif int(input_arr[i]) == 2:
            if float(prob_arr[i]) >= 0.5:
                conf_arr[1][0] = conf_arr[1][0] +1
            else:
                conf_arr[1][1] = conf_arr[1][1] +1

    accuracy = float(conf_arr[0][0] + conf_arr[1][1])/(len(input_arr))
```

`prob_arr` is an array that my classification code returned and a sample array is like this:

```
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.41592955657342651, 1.0, 0.0053405015805891975, 4.5321494433440449e-299, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.70943426182688163, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

`input_arr` is the original class labels for a dataset and it is like this:

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

What my code is trying to do is: I get `prob_arr` and `input_arr` and for each class (1 and 2) I check if they are misclassified or not.

But my code only works for two classes. If I run this code for a multiple classed data, it doesn't work. How can I make this for multiple classes?

For example, for a data set with three classes, it should return: `[[21, 7, 3], [3, 38, 6],[5, 4, 19]]`.

Answer (score 240):

Scikit-Learn provides a `confusion_matrix` function

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

y_actu = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2]
confusion_matrix(y_actu, y_pred)
```

which output a Numpy array

```
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 3]])
```

But you can also create a confusion matrix using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

y_actu = pd.Series([2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2], name='Actual')
y_pred = pd.Series([0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2], name='Predicted')
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
```

You will get a (nicely labeled) Pandas DataFrame:

```
Predicted  0  1  2
Actual
0          3  0  0
1          0  1  2
2          2  1  3
```

If you add `margins=True` like

```
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred, rownames=['Actual'], colnames=['Predicted'], margins=True)
```

you will get also sum for each row and column:

```
Predicted  0  1  2  All
Actual
0          3  0  0    3
1          0  1  2    3
2          2  1  3    6
All        5  2  5   12
```

You can also get a normalized confusion matrix using:

```
df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
df_conf_norm = df_confusion.div(df_confusion.sum(axis=1), axis="index")

Predicted         0         1         2
Actual
0          1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1          0.000000  0.333333  0.666667
2          0.333333  0.166667  0.500000
```

You can plot this confusion_matrix using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_confusion_matrix(df_confusion, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.gray_r):
    plt.matshow(df_confusion, cmap=cmap) # imshow
    #plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(df_confusion.columns))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, df_confusion.columns, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, df_confusion.index)
    #plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel(df_confusion.index.name)
    plt.xlabel(df_confusion.columns.name)


df_confusion = pd.crosstab(y_actu, y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(df_confusion)
```

[image: plot confusion matrix]

Or plot normalized confusion matrix using:

```
plot_confusion_matrix(df_conf_norm)
```

[image: plot confusion matrix normalized]

You might also be interested by this project https://github.com/pandas-ml/pandas-ml and its Pip package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas_ml

With this package confusion matrix can be pretty-printed, plot.
You can binarize a confusion matrix, get class statistics such as TP, TN, FP, FN, ACC, TPR, FPR, FNR, TNR (SPC), LR+, LR-, DOR, PPV, FDR, FOR, NPV and some overall statistics

```py
In [1]: from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
In [2]: y_actu = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
In [3]: y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2]
In [4]: cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred)
In [5]: cm.print_stats()
```

```
Confusion Matrix:

Predicted  0  1  2  __all__
Actual
0          3  0  0        3
1          0  1  2        3
2          2  1  3        6
__all__    5  2  5       12


Overall Statistics:

Accuracy: 0.583333333333
95% CI: (0.27666968568210581, 0.84834777019156982)
No Information Rate: ToDo
P-Value [Acc > NIR]: 0.189264302376
Kappa: 0.354838709677
Mcnemar's Test P-Value: ToDo


Class Statistics:

Classes                                        0          1          2
Population                                    12         12         12
P: Condition positive                          3          3          6
N: Condition negative                          9          9          6
Test outcome positive                          5          2          5
Test outcome negative                          7         10          7
TP: True Positive                              3          1          3
TN: True Negative                              7          8          4
FP: False Positive                             2          1          2
FN: False Negative                             0          2          3
TPR: (Sensitivity, hit rate, recall)           1  0.3333333        0.5
TNR=SPC: (Specificity)                 0.7777778  0.8888889  0.6666667
PPV: Pos Pred Value (Precision)              0.6        0.5        0.6
NPV: Neg Pred Value                            1        0.8  0.5714286
FPR: False-out                         0.2222222  0.1111111  0.3333333
FDR: False Discovery Rate                    0.4        0.5        0.4
FNR: Miss Rate                                 0  0.6666667        0.5
ACC: Accuracy                          0.8333333       0.75  0.5833333
F1 score                                    0.75        0.4  0.5454545
MCC: Matthews correlation coefficient  0.6831301  0.2581989  0.1690309
Informedness                           0.7777778  0.2222222  0.1666667
Markedness                                   0.6        0.3  0.1714286
Prevalence                                  0.25       0.25        0.5
LR+: Positive likelihood ratio               4.5          3        1.5
LR-: Negative likelihood ratio                 0       0.75       0.75
DOR: Diagnostic odds ratio                   inf          4          2
FOR: False omission rate                       0        0.2  0.4285714
```

I noticed that a new Python library about Confusion Matrix named [PyCM](http://www.pycm.ir/) is out: maybe you can have a look.

Answer (score 49):

Nearly a decade has passed, yet the solutions (without sklearn) to this post are convoluted and unnecessarily long. Computing a confusion matrix can be done cleanly in Python in a few lines. For example:

```
import numpy as np

def compute_confusion_matrix(true, pred):
  '''Computes a confusion matrix using numpy for two np.arrays
  true and pred.

  Results are identical (and similar in computation time) to: 
    "from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix"

  However, this function avoids the dependency on sklearn.'''

  K = len(np.unique(true)) # Number of classes 
  result = np.zeros((K, K))

  for i in range(len(true)):
    result[true[i]][pred[i]] += 1

  return result
```

Comment: and you can make it  >10x faster  with `@numba.jit` : numpy : 83 ms per loop, numba:  2.4 ms per loop (except first call )

Comment: Isn't this working only if labels are positive intergers? what about string and floats?

Comment: @Ali Gröch - just map the labels with a helper function. The helper function can be as simple as `return dict(zip(range(len(np.unique(labels))), np.unique(labels)))`

Answer (score 20):

[Scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) (which I recommend using anyways) has it included in the `metrics` module:

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

>>> y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
>>> y_pred = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2]
>>> confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

array([[3, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want scikit-learn to do the work for you:

```
import numpy

actual = numpy.array(actual)
predicted = numpy.array(predicted)

# calculate the confusion matrix; labels is numpy array of classification labels
cm = numpy.zeros((len(labels), len(labels)))
for a, p in zip(actual, predicted):
    cm[a][p] += 1

# also get the accuracy easily with numpy
accuracy = (actual == predicted).sum() / float(len(actual))
```

Or take a look at a more complete implementation here in [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/confusionmatrix.html).

Answer (score 8):

### A Dependency Free Multiclass Confusion Matrix

```
# A Simple Confusion Matrix Implementation
def confusionmatrix(actual, predicted, normalize = False):
    """
    Generate a confusion matrix for multiple classification
    @params:
        actual      - a list of integers or strings for known classes
        predicted   - a list of integers or strings for predicted classes
        normalize   - optional boolean for matrix normalization
    @return:
        matrix      - a 2-dimensional list of pairwise counts
    """
    unique = sorted(set(actual))
    matrix = [[0 for _ in unique] for _ in unique]
    imap   = {key: i for i, key in enumerate(unique)}
    # Generate Confusion Matrix
    for p, a in zip(predicted, actual):
        matrix[imap[p]][imap[a]] += 1
    # Matrix Normalization
    if normalize:
        sigma = sum([sum(matrix[imap[i]]) for i in unique])
        matrix = [row for row in map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: j / sigma, i)), matrix)]
    return matrix
```

The approach here is to pair up the unique classes found in the `actual` vector into a 2-dimensional list. From there, we simply iterate through the zipped `actual` and `predicted` vectors and populate the counts using the indices to access the matrix positions.

**Usage**

```
cm = confusionmatrix(
    [1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1], # actual
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2]  # predicted
)

# And The Output
print(cm)
[[2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

*Note:* the `actual` classes are along the columns and the `predicted` classes are along the rows.

```
# Actual
# 0  1  2
  #  #  #   
[[2, 1, 0], # 0
 [0, 2, 1], # 1  Predicted
 [1, 2, 1]] # 2
```

**Class Names Can be Strings or Integers**

```
cm = confusionmatrix(
    ["B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"], # actual
    ["A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C"]  # predicted
)

# And The Output
print(cm)
[[2, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

**You Can Also Return The Matrix With Proportions (Normalization)**

```
cm = confusionmatrix(
    ["B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"], # actual
    ["A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "C", "A", "C"], # predicted
    normalize = True
)

# And The Output
print(cm)
[[0.2, 0.1, 0.0], [0.0, 0.2, 0.1], [0.1, 0.2, 0.1]]
```

### A More Robust Solution

Since writing this post, I've updated my library implementation to be a class  that uses a confusion matrix representation internally to compute statistics, in addition to pretty printing the confusion matrix itself. See this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/greenstick/ec03f0bfebf5679a00b7f096adc10657).

**Example Usage**

```
# Actual & Predicted Classes
actual      = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"]
predicted   = ["A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C"]

# Initialize Performance Class
performance = Performance(actual, predicted)

# Print Confusion Matrix
performance.tabulate()
```

With the output:

```
===================================
        Aᴬ      Bᴬ      Cᴬ

Aᴾ      3       2       1

Bᴾ      1       4       1

Cᴾ      1       0       4

Note: classᴾ = Predicted, classᴬ = Actual
===================================
```

And for the normalized matrix:

```
# Print Normalized Confusion Matrix
performance.tabulate(normalized = True)
```

With the normalized output:

```
===================================
        Aᴬ      Bᴬ      Cᴬ

Aᴾ      17.65%  11.76%  5.88%

Bᴾ      5.88%   23.53%  5.88%

Cᴾ      5.88%   0.00%   23.53%

Note: classᴾ = Predicted, classᴬ = Actual
===================================
```

Answer (score 4):

This function creates confusion matrices for any number of classes.

```
def create_conf_matrix(expected, predicted, n_classes):
    m = [[0] * n_classes for i in range(n_classes)]
    for pred, exp in zip(predicted, expected):
        m[pred][exp] += 1
    return m

def calc_accuracy(conf_matrix):
    t = sum(sum(l) for l in conf_matrix)
    return sum(conf_matrix[i][i] for i in range(len(conf_matrix))) / t
```

In contrast to your function above, you have to extract the predicted classes before calling the function, based on your classification results, i.e. sth. like

```
[1 if p < .5 else 2 for p in classifications]
```

Comment: This like gives a syntax error, I am not good enough in Python to fix it though :)

     m = [[0] * n_classes] for i in range(n_classes)]
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think you need one more `[`: `m = [[[0] * ...`

Comment: Actually, it's one less:)---fixed.

Comment: You might have created *transposed* confusion matrix.

Answer (score 3):

A numpy-only solution for any number of classes that doesn't require looping:

```
import numpy as np

classes = 3
true = np.random.randint(0, classes, 50)
pred = np.random.randint(0, classes, 50)

np.bincount(true * classes + pred).reshape((classes, classes))
```

Comment: A little improvement:
`classes = np.unique(pred).size`

Comment: isn't `true * classes` is an element-wise multiplication?

Comment: This is a great and really fast solution! Unfortunately it doesnt work if not all classes are represented in both arrays: `len(np.unique(true)) != classes` or `len(np.unique(pred)) != classes`.

Comment: @Rendicahya: better: `classes=np.unique(true).size`. The predicted set `pred` may not include all classes present in `true` (e.g. if the predictor has bias). On the other hand, it's generally reasonable to expect hat all classes in `pred` are present in `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code more concise and (sometimes) to run faster using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/). For example, in two-classes case your function can be rewritten as (see [`mply.acc()`](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/browser/trunk/mlpy/_bmetrics.py#L130)):

```
def accuracy(actual, predicted):
    """accuracy = (tp + tn) / ts

    , where:    

        ts - Total Samples
        tp - True Positives
        tn - True Negatives
    """
    return (actual == predicted).sum() / float(len(actual))
```

, where:

```
actual    = (numpy.array(input_arr) == 2)
predicted = (numpy.array(prob_arr) < 0.5)
```

Comment: Instead of sum, use `.mean()` and avoid the division (noting that the answer is from 11 years ago and that Numpy may not have had the mean function at that time).

Answer (score 2):

It can be simply calculated as below:

```
def confusionMatrix(actual, pred):

   TP = (actual==pred)[actual].sum()
   TN = (actual==pred)[~actual].sum()
   FP = (actual!=pred)[~actual].sum()
   FN = (actual!=pred)[actual].sum()

   return [[TP, TN], [FP, FN]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain your answer and why it may be the answer the questioner is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A small change of cgnorthcutt's solution, considering the string type variables

```
def get_confusion_matrix(l1, l2):

    assert len(l1)==len(l2), "Two lists have different size."

    K = len(np.unique(l1))

    # create label-index value
    label_index = dict(zip(np.unique(l1), np.arange(K)))

    result = np.zeros((K, K))
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        result[label_index[l1[i]]][label_index[l2[i]]] += 1

    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You should map from classes to a row in your confusion matrix.

Here the mapping is trivial:

```
def row_of_class(classe):
    return {1: 0, 2: 1}[classe]
```

In your loop, compute `expected_row`, `correct_row`, and increment `conf_arr[expected_row][correct_row]`. You'll even have less code than what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, you're going to need to change your probability array.  Instead of having one number for each instance and classifying based on whether or not it is greater than 0.5, you're going to need a list of scores (one for each class), then take the largest of the scores as the class that was chosen (a.k.a. argmax).

You could use a dictionary to hold the probabilities for each classification:

```
prob_arr = [{classification_id: probability}, ...]
```

Choosing a classification would be something like:

```
for instance_scores in prob_arr :
    predicted_classes = [cls for (cls, score) in instance_scores.iteritems() if score = max(instance_scores.values())]
```

This handles the case where two classes have the same scores. You can get one score, by choosing the first one in that list, but how you handle that depends on what you're classifying.

Once you have your list of predicted classes and a list of expected classes you can use code like [Torsten Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148543/how-to-write-a-confusion-matrix-in-python#answer-2148747)'s to create the confusion array and calculate the accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple class to build a confusion matrix without the need to depend on a machine learning library.

The class can be used such as:

```py
labels = ["cat", "dog", "velociraptor", "kraken", "pony"]
confusionMatrix = ConfusionMatrix(labels)

confusionMatrix.update("cat", "cat")
confusionMatrix.update("cat", "dog")
...
confusionMatrix.update("kraken", "velociraptor")
confusionMatrix.update("velociraptor", "velociraptor")

confusionMatrix.plot()
```

The class ConfusionMatrix:

```py
import pylab
import collections
import numpy as np


class ConfusionMatrix:
    def __init__(self, labels):
        self.labels = labels
        self.confusion_dictionary = self.build_confusion_dictionary(labels)

    def update(self, predicted_label, expected_label):
        self.confusion_dictionary[expected_label][predicted_label] += 1

    def build_confusion_dictionary(self, label_set):
        expected_labels = collections.OrderedDict()

        for expected_label in label_set:
            expected_labels[expected_label] = collections.OrderedDict()

            for predicted_label in label_set:
                expected_labels[expected_label][predicted_label] = 0.0

        return expected_labels

    def convert_to_matrix(self, dictionary):
        length = len(dictionary)
        confusion_dictionary = np.zeros((length, length))

        i = 0
        for row in dictionary:
            j = 0
            for column in dictionary:
                confusion_dictionary[i][j] = dictionary[row][column]
                j += 1
            i += 1

        return confusion_dictionary

    def get_confusion_matrix(self):
        matrix = self.convert_to_matrix(self.confusion_dictionary)
        return self.normalize(matrix)

    def normalize(self, matrix):
        amin = np.amin(matrix)
        amax = np.amax(matrix)

        return [[(((y - amin) * (1 - 0)) / (amax - amin)) for y in x] for x in matrix]

    def plot(self):
        matrix = self.get_confusion_matrix()

        pylab.figure()
        pylab.imshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest', cmap=pylab.cm.jet)
        pylab.title("Confusion Matrix")

        for i, vi in enumerate(matrix):
            for j, vj in enumerate(vi):
                pylab.text(j, i+.1, "%.1f" % vj, fontsize=12)

        pylab.colorbar()

        classes = np.arange(len(self.labels))
        pylab.xticks(classes, self.labels)
        pylab.yticks(classes, self.labels)

        pylab.ylabel('Expected label')
        pylab.xlabel('Predicted label')
        pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Only with numpy, we can do as follow considering efficiency:

```
def confusion_matrix(pred, label, nc=None):
    assert pred.size == label.size
    if nc is None:
        nc = len(unique(label))
        logging.debug("Number of classes assumed to be {}".format(nc))

    confusion = np.zeros([nc, nc])
    # avoid the confusion with `0`
    tran_pred = pred + 1
    for i in xrange(nc):    # current class
        mask = (label == i)
        masked_pred = mask * tran_pred
        cls, counts = unique(masked_pred, return_counts=True)
        # discard the first item
        cls = [cl - 1 for cl in cls][1:]
        counts = counts[1:]
        for cl, count in zip(cls, counts):
            confusion[i, cl] = count
    return confusion
```

For other features such as plot, mean-IoU, see [my repositories](https://github.com/meijieru/tensorflow-dpn/blob/master/src/utils.py#L178).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation that handles an unequal number of classes in the predicted and actual labels (see examples 3 and 4). I hope this helps!

For folks just learning this, here's a quick review. The labels for the columns indicate the predicted class, and the labels for the rows indicate the correct class. In example 1, we have [3 1] on the top row. Again, rows indicate truth, so this means that the correct label is "0" and there are 4 examples with ground truth label of "0". Columns indicate predictions, so we have 3/4 of the samples correctly labeled as "0", but 1/4 was incorrectly labeled as a "1".

```
def confusion_matrix(actual, predicted):
    classes       = np.unique(np.concatenate((actual,predicted)))
    confusion_mtx = np.empty((len(classes),len(classes)),dtype=np.int)
    for i,a in enumerate(classes):
        for j,p in enumerate(classes):
            confusion_mtx[i,j] = np.where((actual==a)*(predicted==p))[0].shape[0]
    return confusion_mtx
```

---

Example 1:

```
actual    = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0])
predicted = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1])
confusion_matrix(actual,predicted)

   0  1
0  3  1
1  0  4
```

---

Example 2:

```
actual    = np.array(["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"])
predicted = np.array(["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","a"])
confusion_matrix(actual,predicted)

   0  1
0  4  0
1  1  3
```

---

Example 3:

```
actual    = np.array(["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b"])
predicted = np.array(["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","z"]) # <-- notice the 3rd class, "z"
confusion_matrix(actual,predicted)

   0  1  2
0  4  0  0
1  0  3  1
2  0  0  0
```

---

Example 4:

```
actual    = np.array(["a","a","a","x","x","b","b","b"]) # <-- notice the 4th class, "x"
predicted = np.array(["a","a","a","a","b","b","b","z"])
confusion_matrix(actual,predicted)

   0  1  2  3
0  3  0  0  0
1  0  2  0  1
2  1  1  0  0
3  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the sklearn solution is really clean its really slow if you compare it to numpy only solutions. Let me give you an example and a better/faster solution.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

num_classes = 3

true = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, 10000000)
pred = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, 10000000)
```

For reference first the sklearn solution

```
start = time.time()
confusion = confusion_matrix(true, pred)

print('time: ' + str(time.time() - start)) # time: 9.31
```

And now a much faster solution using numpy only. Instead of iterating through all samples, in this case we iterate through the confusion matrix and calc the value for each cell. This makes the process really fast.

```
start = time.time()

confusion = np.zeros((num_classes, num_classes)).astype(np.int64)

for i in range(num_classes):
    for j in range(num_classes):
        confusion[i][j] = np.sum(np.logical_and(true == i, pred == j))

print('time: ' + str(time.time() - start)) # time: 0.34
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually got sick of always needing to code my confusion matrix on my experiments. So, I've built my own simple pypi package for it.

Just install it with `pip install easycm`

Then, import the function with `from easycm import plot_confusion_matrix`

Finally, plot your data with `plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)`

Answer (score 0):

I actually got sick of always needing to code my confusion matrix on my experiments. So, I've built my own simple pypi package for it.

Just install it with

```
pip install easycm
```

Then, import the function and use it.

```
from easycm import plot_confusion_matrix

...

plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a library function with which we can draw confusion matrix

Just find from the machine learning model the predicted value of target variable  `y_pred_M` vs the actual value of the target variable `y_test_M`

And as labels put the different categories in my case, it is grades of students, and we can get the true labels on y-axis, and predicted label on the x-axis

```
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test_M, y_pred_M)

cm_display = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix, display_labels = ['A',
            'B', 
            'C',  
            'D'])


cm_display.plot()

plt.show()
```

Please refer this blog for complete details
[Let us make confusion matrix for cross validation based results](https://kanchanardj.medium.com/let-us-make-confusion-matrix-for-cross-validation-based-results-3bb56196e839)

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, post a complete answer with all appropriate imports and a working example. Thank you.

Comment: I will remember in the future thanks