# How do I generate Tensorflow Confusion Matrix from "output_graph.pb" and "output_labels.txt"?

Tags: tensorflow, confusion-matrix

So I have followed this tutorial and retrained using my own images.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

So I now have an "output_graph.pb" and a "output_labels.txt" (which I can use with other code to classify images).

But how do I actually generate a confusion matrix using a folder of testing images (or at least with the images it was trained on)?

There is https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/confusion_matrix
but that doesnt seem very helpful.

This thread seems to just be using numbers to represent labels rather than actual files, but not really sure: [how to create confusion matrix for classification in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051687/how-to-create-confusion-matrix-for-classification-in-tensorflow)

And Im not really sure how to use the code in this thread either:
[How do i create Confusion matrix of predicted and ground truth labels with Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756710/how-do-i-create-confusion-matrix-of-predicted-and-ground-truth-labels-with-tenso)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create you confusion matrix manually, using something like this steps:

- Modify the label_image example to print out just the top label.
- Write a script to call the modified label_image repeatedly for all images in a folder.
- Have the script print out the ground truth label, and then call label_image to print the predicted one.

You should now have a text list of all your labels in the console, something like this:

apple,apple
apple,pear
pear,pear
pear,orange
...

Now, create a spreadsheet with both row and column names for all the labels:

```
       | apple | pear | orange
-------+----------------------
apple  |
pear   |
orange |
```

The value for each cell will be the number of pairs that show up in your console list for row, column. For a small set of images you can compute this manually, or you can write a script to calculate this if there's too many.