# Calculate Accuracy for multilabel classification with FastText

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix, fasttext

I have a multi label classification task with FastText. I have to compute the Confusion Matrix for it. I have solved already the problem to compute the CM for a single label. This is the Python script for it:

```
import argparse
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

def parse_labels(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        return np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[9:], f.read().split())))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Display confusion matrix.')
    parser.add_argument('test', help='Path to test labels')
    parser.add_argument('predict', help='Path to predictions')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    test_labels = parse_labels(args.test)
    print("Test labels:%d (sample)\n%s" % (len(test_labels),test_labels[:1]) )
    pred_labels = parse_labels(args.predict)
    print("Predicted labels:%d (sample)\n%s" % (len(pred_labels),pred_labels[:1]) )
    eq = test_labels == pred_labels
    print("Accuracy: " + str(eq.sum() / len(test_labels)))
    print(confusion_matrix(test_labels, pred_labels))
```

This will output something like

```
Test labels:539328 (sample)
['pop']
Predicted labels:539328 (sample)
['unknown']
Accuracy: 0.17639914857
[[6126    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [  55    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [   6    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 ..., 
 [   0    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]
 [   0    0    0 ...,    0    0    0]]
```

The problem is that in the specific case of a multi label task, this is not working properly because I'm computing accuracy

```
eq = test_labels == pred_labels
eq.sum() / len(test_labels)
```

that works ok when the files have one column / labels, but not when the predictions output from FastText is a two columns / labels file.

Comment: I've written a confusion matrix implementation for multiple classification that computes a number of statistics. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030708/2206251

Comment: That's awesome thanks!