# How can I get a confusion matrix of a single run in sklearn cross_validate?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I do something like:

```
scoring = ["accuracy", "balanced_accuracy", "f1", "precision", "recall", "roc_auc"]

scores = cross_validate(SVC(), my_x, my_y, scoring = scoring , cv=5, verbose=3, return_train_score=True, return_estimator=True)
```

how can I get a confusion matrix of a single validation run, e.g. the first one or ideally the best one?

I don't need a plot or something beautiful, only the numbers. If I could see at least the split, then I could recalculate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a confusion matrix in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148543/how-to-write-a-confusion-matrix-in-python)

Comment: Use grid_search to find optimal model then do matrix off of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cross-validation to perform something quite specific during each iteration, maybe it is best to use a CV splitter like `StratifiedKFold` :

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.svm import SVC

svm = SVC()
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

scores = []
results = []
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X, y):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = svm.predict(y_test)
    scores.append(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)) # use other scoring as prefered 
    results.append(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

This will compute the confusion matrix for each of the five iterations and store them in `results`. If you want to get the confusion matrix of the best validation round, you can additionally compute the scoring metric in the loop as well (see the `scores` list) and retrieve the corresponding confusion matrix.